# Why is the sprintf converting only half of my uint64_t data?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>



using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint64_t a = 0xffffffffffffffff;
    int c = 3;
    char b[16];
    sprintf(b, "%X", a);
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is printing and storing half of the fs, i need the rest of them, how do i do this?

Comment: Probably it converts only half of your data, because it doesn't know your data is 64 bits, not 32. Try using appropriate size specifier together with `%X`, possibly `"%llX"` or `"%I64X"`.

Comment: Your compiler should show you a warning similar to: `warning: format '%X' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 3 has type 'uint64_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'}` if not you should check if you can increase your warning level.

Comment: And this is why the cstdio should be avoided. It's too easy to write UB bugs for beginners.

Comment: @CiaPan Curious, where from do you got `"%I64X"`? Och nevermind found it! [windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019).

Comment: MSVC :) Doc [Format specification syntax: printf and wprintf functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019#size-prefixes-for-printf-and-wprintf-format-type-specifiers), section [Size Prefixes for printf and wprintf Format-Type Specifiers
](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019#size-prefixes-for-printf-and-wprintf-format-type-specifiers). Oh, the comment can't properly format such long link. Or maybe a link with a hash.

Comment: Oh, MSVC and their weird language extensions ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yup. But we don't know what platform OP uses, do we?

Comment: @CiaPan fair, but AFAIK MSVC supports `<cinttypes>` just fine which is portable.

Comment: @CiaPan Which is why it is strange to suggest something that only works on one platform, rather than suggesting alternative that works on all standard compliant platforms.

Comment: @eerorika Hmmm, didn't I sugest any alternative...?

Comment: @CiaPan You suggested two alternatives, one of which are wrong, and the other is non-portable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are invoking *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type.

The type format to print `uint64_t` in uppercase hex is `PRIX64`, defined in the header [`<cinttypes>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cinttypes).

Also don't forget to allocate for terminating null-character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>    // sprintf()
#include <cinttypes> // PRIX64 (and its family) is defined in this header



using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint64_t a = 0xffffffffffffffff;
    int c = 3;
    char b[17]; // allocate also for terminating null-character
    sprintf(b, "%" PRIX64, a); // use correct format
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the `%llX` specifier is standard since C++11. Much simpler than the PRIX64 macro.

Comment: @AdrianMole I think `PRIX64` is the standard. `%llX` is for `unsigned long long`.

Comment: And `unsigned long long` is defined to be *at least 64 bits* in C++11.

Comment: @AdrianMole And thus potentially not be the same as `uint64_t` (on some future systems).

Comment: @AdrianMole To expand on what MikeCAT said, `unsigned long long` is not guaranteed to be a `uint64_t` [at least 64](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) is not the same as *exactly* 64 and that causes UB.

Comment: but there is no difference if I change from 17 to 16, what is it for? What happen if I don't?

Comment: Out-of-bound write **may** break around data. [Here is an example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tx3kXwk07UTFcCxH): 0 is printed instead of 4.

Comment: @AStoach167 then the 17th byte overwrites the first byte of the next variable in memory. Which could be something harmless like `c` or `a`, or it could be the return address and crash your program. And if it works today, tomorrow the compiler might change its mind and make it crash.

Comment: @user253751 Or more generally: Behaviour of the program is undefined and anything might happen.